# Can you tell whether an Iron Flask is filled, and with what?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, magic-items

An [Iron Flask](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/wondrousItems.htm#ironFlask), when found, has a random chance of already containing a creature. I can't determine from the SRD's description if there's a way to tell its contents.

Is there any way to tell whether a given Iron Flask is already filled, and if so what it contains?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flask is open = it is empty.

---

Flask is closed = do some magic :-).

Your best friend is [Divination school](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicOverview/spellDescriptions.htm#divination):

This item *uses* the spell [Trap the Soul](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/trapTheSoul.htm), which has *permament* duration.
This duration is defined as:

> The energy remains as long as the effect does. This means the spell is vulnerable to dispel magic.

I would say that you can use for example [Detect Magic](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/detectMagic.htm) spell or [Arcane Sight](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/arcaneSight.htm). There is note in *Detect Magic* which says:

> Outsiders and elementals are not magical in themselves, but if they
>   are summoned, the conjuration spell registers.

With this spell you are not able to say, what creature is in.

You can also use the [Identify](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/identify.htm) spell. It says that:

> The spell determines all magic properties of a single magic item, including how to activate those functions (if appropriate), and how many charges are left (if any).

Another spell is [Analyze Dweomer](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/analyzeDweomer.htm) it says:

> In the case of a magic item, you learn its functions, how to activate its functions (if appropriate), and how many charges are left (if it uses charges).

There are also not *direct* spells. For example [Contact Other Plane](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/contactOtherPlane.htm), [Limited Wish](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/limitedWish.htm) or [Wish](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/wish.htm).

And some not mentioned spells for Clerics: [Augury](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/augury.htm), [Divination](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/divination.htm), [Commune](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/commune.htm) and of course also [Miracle](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/miracle.htm).

With some of these spells you should be also able to say (with some certainty) which creature is *in* the flask.

---

Last, but not least - I don't know which *magic appearance* you use for your magic items. Since the flask should be covered with runes it is up to the DM if those runes says for example: *This is the Iron Flask.* or if it says: *This is the Iron Flask currently containing Glabrezu.*